# Only one form submitting correctly with react hooks

Tags: reactjs

I have a main `App` component that has a form *and* another component that also renders a separate form. I want the second form to submit correctly using its separate `handleSecondSubmit` function, but it does not seem to use it.

Here's the full code and a StackBlitz: [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rvn3j8)

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const SecondForm = () => {
  const { handleSubmit, register } = useForm();
  const handleSecondSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("2nd form");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(handleSecondSubmit)}>
      <input name="test" type="text" ref={register({ required: true })} />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, errors } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

  console.log(watch("example"));

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input name="example" defaultValue="test" ref={register} />

        <input name="exampleRequired" ref={register({ required: true })} />
        {errors.exampleRequired && <span>This field is required</span>}

        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
      <SecondForm />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Can someone explain what's happening here? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `handleSubmit` directly when applying the handler, and the signature for the returned function has the `event` as the second argument (*the first being the data*)

```js
const SecondForm = () => {
  const { handleSubmit, register } = useForm();
  const handleSecondSubmit = (data, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("2nd form", data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleSecondSubmit)}>
      <input name="test" type="text" ref={register({ required: true })} />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v7cdfh

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
 return (
    <form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(handleSecondSubmit(e))}>
      <input name="test" type="text" ref={register({ required: true })} />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};
```

you forgot to pass `e` to `handleSecondSubmit(e)`

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need to pass the `onSubmit` event object through to your second form's handler.

```
onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(handleSecondSubmit(e))}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fduvdv